# Horizontal Carousel or ScrollView with text over image

Tags: android

I'm trying to figure out the best approach to design a horizontal scrollview from android >= 2.1  with some text over the image that when scroll if end is reached it starts showing the first items again hence carousel behavior.

You can continue scrolling horizontally, forever, and the first item shows up again when the end is reached, for example when scrolling swiping to the left. It can be a view pager with an adapter, a carousel but not horizontal scrollview as it does not support some android device.

[image]
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: are u trying to do it in above 3.0 ?

Comment: yes the ViewPager is the best solution

Comment: @Dimitri Do you have any example for this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html)? As it is available in the [Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html). I would insist to use ViewPager instead of HorizontalScrollView or Gallery. You can check an [example for ViewPager](https://github.com/lalit3686/ViewPagerDemo) from my github.

**UPDATE**

To show multiple views inside a Fragment you can use [getPageWidth()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#getPageWidth%28int%29). Check [here](http://commonsware.com/blog/2012/08/20/multiple-view-viewpager-options.html) for reference.

Comment: Can you provide me with a viewpager that uses an adapter ?

Comment: Added link to github in the answer itself.

Comment: nice one is it compatible with 2.1 ? and can i display 3 views in same screen

Comment: I'm new to this but is this the same effect as Mint app? In the mint app a small subsection of the screen can be carousel. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Guys : if i want to 3 view in screen and center one should highlight then how can i do it. Please update me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For future people looking for this, here's an excellent library that fit my needs for a similar problem!
https://github.com/sparrow007/CarouselRecyclerview