# android: continuous Tab Bar

Tags: java, android, view, tabs, android-actionbar

is there a Way to implement a continuous button/tab Bar?

The Action bar is already in use for the "main tab" selection.

The "sub tab" selection should be some Buttons which you can scroll infinite (if the Bar ends the first Button is shown again)[image]

Comment: Look's like you want to implement a carousel. Try this tutorial to get you started: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/02/01/android-carousel-design-pattern/

Comment: Thanks. If you write an answer I'll mark is as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to implement a carousel, try [this](http://smashingmagazine.com/2013/02/01/android-carousel-design-pattern) tutorial.
Or you could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15896373/horizontal-carousel-or-scrollview-with-text-over-image) approach which uses a ViewPager. Good luck!